# Group, Sort and Count in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, count, group-by

I'm trying to `GROUP`, `SORT` and `COUNT` in a single query one of my table named 'commodities'.

Here is a simplification of my `MySql` table :

```
family  sub_family  name        detailed_name 
Agro    Grains      Wheat       Wheat per 1 mt
Agro    Grains      Corn        Corn per 1 mt
Agro    Grains      Sugar       Sugar per 1 mt
Agro    Fruits      Apple       Apple red
Agro    Fruits      Apple       Apple green
Agro    Fruits      Apple       Apple yellow
Agro    Fruits      Lemon       Lemon classic
Wood    Tree        Lemon       Lemon in logs
Wood    Tree        Oak         Oak in logs
Wood    Tree        Epicea      Epicea in logs
Wood    Packaging   Kraftliner  Krafliner 3mm
```

I would like to :

1. `GROUP` by `name`
2. `SORT` by `family`, `sub_family` and lastly `name`
3. `COUNT`the numbers of rows for each `family`, `sub_family` and then `name` (IN THE SAME `sub_family`)

So far I managed to do everything but `COUNT` in the same `sub_family`.

Indeed, the following query :

```
SELECT 
    TableC.family,
    TableC.NbrFamily,
    TableB.sub_family,
    TableB.NbrSubFamily,
    TableA.name,
    TableA.NbrName
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        family,
        sub_family,
        name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT commodities.id) AS NbrName 
    FROM commodities GROUP BY name
) TableA
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        sub_family,
        COUNT(DISTINCT commodities.id) AS NbrSubFamily 
    FROM commodities GROUP BY sub_family
) TableB
ON (TableA.sub_family = TableB.sub_family)
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        family,
        COUNT(DISTINCT commodities.id) AS NbrFamily 
    FROM commodities GROUP BY family
) TableC
ON (TableA.family = TableC.family)
GROUP BY TableA.name
ORDER BY TableA.family,TableA.sub_family,TableA.name
```

which results in the following :

```
family  NbrFamily  sub_family  NbrSubFamily  name        NbrName
Agro    7          Grains      3             Wheat       1       
Agro    7          Grains      3             Corn        1        
Agro    7          Grains      3             Sugar       1       
Agro    7          Fruits      4             Apple       3
Agro    7          Fruits      4             Lemon       2
Wood    4          Tree        3             Lemon       2
Wood    4          Tree        3             Oak         1     
Wood    4          Tree        3             Epicea      1  
Wood    4          Packaging   1             Kraftliner  1
```

You can see that `NbrName` counts *Lemon* 2 times but I would like it to count it only 1 time because one *lemon* is in *Fruits* `sub_family` and the other in *Tree* `sub_family`.

[UPDATE] : Here are my desired results :

```
   family  NbrFamily  sub_family  NbrSubFamily  name        NbrName
    Agro    7          Grains      3             Wheat       1       
    Agro    7          Grains      3             Corn        1        
    Agro    7          Grains      3             Sugar       1       
    Agro    7          Fruits      4             Apple       3
    Agro    7          Fruits      4             Lemon       1
    Wood    4          Tree        3             Lemon       1
    Wood    4          Tree        3             Oak         1     
    Wood    4          Tree        3             Epicea      1  
    Wood    4          Packaging   1             Kraftliner  1
```

Comment: How can you sort by columns that have multiple values for your groups?  I think you are confused.  Edit your query and include your *desired* results.

Comment: According to your post **'Lemon' 2 times but I would like it to count it only 1** according to your desired result **Agro    7          Fruits      4             Lemon       2
    Wood    4          Tree        3             Lemon       2** so what is your real goal is?

Comment: My question is probably not clear enough. As you can see, 'Lemon' is getting counted 2 times for each Lemon (one in 'Fruits' sub_family and the other in 'Tree' sub_family). But I would like to count it only 1 time since the two 'Lemon' do NOT belong to the same sub_family. One is a fruit and the other is a tree.

Comment: there is no `core` and `id` columns in data sample provided but you reference to them in query

Comment: your query result provided is not match to the query provided here is proof http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9206/3  so your query return 1 row with lemon not 2

Comment: @user3203796 but if 3rd lemon will be from the same `wood` but another `sub family` what NbrName value should be?

Comment: @Alex you're right there was a 'typo' mistake in my query, it should have been 'name' and not 'core' on the `SORT` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my guess of what you are asking for http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9206/16

because it brings desired result:

```
 SELECT A.family, C.NbrFamily,A.sub_family,B.NbrSubFamily,A.name,COUNT(A.Name)
 FROM  commodities as A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT family,sub_family,COUNT(Name) AS NbrSubFamily 
  FROM commodities 
  GROUP BY family,sub_family
) B
ON A.sub_family = B.sub_family 
  AND A.family = B.family 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT family,COUNT(Name) AS NbrFamily 
  FROM commodities 
  GROUP BY family
) C

ON  A.family = C.family 
GROUP BY A.family,A.sub_family,A.name
ORDER BY A.id
```