# MySQL - Group, Sort, Count on an UNION in a single Query

Tags: mysql, count, union, alias

I'm trying to `GROUP`, `SORT` and `COUNT` in a single query on 2 tables.
One is called 'commodities_customs' and the other 'commodities_imf'.

Here is a simplification of my 'commodities_customs' table :

```
family  sub_family  name        detailed_name 
Agro    Grains      Wheat       Wheat per 1 mt
Agro    Grains      Corn        Corn per 1 mt
Agro    Grains      Sugar       Sugar per 1 mt
Agro    Fruits      Apple       Apple red
Agro    Fruits      Apple       Apple green
Agro    Fruits      Apple       Apple yellow
Agro    Fruits      Lemon       Lemon classic
Wood    Tree        Lemon       Lemon in logs
Wood    Tree        Oak         Oak in logs
Wood    Tree        Epicea      Epicea in logs
Wood    Packaging   Kraftliner  Krafliner 3mm
```

And here is a simplification of my 'commodities_imf' table :

```
family  sub_family  name        detailed_name 
Agro    Grains      Wheat       CME Wheat
Agro    Grains      Corn        CME Corn
Wood    Tree        Cedar       CME Cedar in logs
Wood    Tree        Oak         CME Oak in logs
Wood    Tree        Lemon       CME Lemon
Wood    Packaging   Kraftliner  CME Kraftliner
```

I can't merge the two tables in one because there are many other columns which are different.

So basically, I'm trying to

1. Merge the two tables in one (I'm using `UNION ALL` for that but I'm not sure it's the right solution)
2. `GROUP` by 'name'
3. `SORT` by 'family',sub_family' and lastly 'name'
4. `COUNT` the numbers of rows for each 'family','sub_family' and then 'name' (IN THE SAME sub_family and family)

I previously asked for help on that query on that topic :
[MySQL - Group, Sort and Count in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680707/mysql-group-sort-and-count-in-a-single-query). It can be interesting to check it.

But now, I'm trying to do the same kind of query but on a merge of two tables.
Here is what I'm expecting as a result :

```
family  NbrFamily  sub_family  NbrSubFamily name        NbrName
Agro    9          Fruits      4            Apple       3
Agro    9          Fruits      4            Lemon       1
Agro    9          Grains      5            Corn        2
Agro    9          Grains      5            Sugar       1
Agro    9          Grains      5            Wheat       2
Wood    8          Packaging   2            Kraftliner  2
Wood    8          Tree        6           Cedar        1
Wood    8          Tree        6           Epicea       1
Wood    8          Tree        6           Lemon        2
Wood    8          Tree        6           Oak          2
```

I've re-used a SQLfiddle with my new (compared to the other question linked above) 'union' requirements for you : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b55eea/7

I've read that the problem might come from Common Table Requirements not being handled by `MySQL`. Am I right ? Do you have any clue on what I could do to overpass that ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to use alias table `TableA` in other parts of the query, but it does not exist. If you reuse the `UNION ALL` part of the `TableA`, then it creates your desired results - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b55eea/10

Comment: You rock @Sean. Post it as an answer for validation if you want.